# Loop over each line and store each word in a line and make a data frame in R

Tags: string, r, loops, dataframe

I have the following file:

```
[1]/tI /tam /tCharlotte   
[2]/ti /tam /tcharlotte   
[3]/tYou /tare /tsmart  
[4]/tyou /tare /tsmart
```

And I want the output data frame to have the following form:

```
word      gloss  
I         i  
am        am      
Charlotte charlotte    
You       you    
are       are    
smart     smart
```

Is it possible to write a code for that? Do I need to separate the file by tab?

Comment: Are the [1], [2], ... part of the file or is that just output from R?

Comment: Are the "/t" supposed to be tab characters?  In most languages that's "\t" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is similar to the one of @csgillespie but everyting is done in one command (once the data is read).

Read the data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "/tI /tam /tCharlotte   
/ti /tam /tcharlotte   
/tYou /tare /tsmart  
/tyou /tare /tsmart", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create data frame:

```
structure(
 as.data.frame(
  lapply(
   lapply(list(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(FALSE, TRUE)),
          function(y) lapply(strsplit(
                              apply(dat, 1, "paste", collapse = ""), "/t"),
                             function(x) x[nchar(x) > 0])[y]),
   unlist)),
 .Names = c("word", "gloss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't entirely clear. For example,

1. Do you have the numbers [1], [2], ... in your file?
2. Are even rows just lower case versions of odd rows?

Ignoring the numbers and assuming that odd and even rows differ, one solution is:

```
##Read in the data. 
tmp = read.table(textConnection("/tI /tam /tCharlotte   
/ti /tam /tcharlotte   
/tYou /tare /tsmart  
/tyou /tare /tsmart"), sep="\n", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

##Take the odd rows
##gsub: remove white space
##strsplit: split the string on "\t"
##unlist: go from a list to a vector
c1 = unlist(
    strsplit(
        gsub(" ", "", tmp[seq(1,nrow(tmp), 2),]), "/t"))

##Ditto the even rows
c2 = unlist(
    strsplit(
        gsub(" ", "", tmp[seq(2,nrow(tmp), 2),]), "/t"))
```

This gives us two vectors that we can put into a data frame:

```
dd = data.frame(c1 = c1, c2 = c2)
```

I presume you don't want the empty rows, so just remove them:

```
dd[apply(dd, 1, function(i) sum(nchar(i))>0),]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the code! My actual file is more complex than that. So in odd number lines, there are words from a language (not english), and in even number lines, there are English translations for each word. There're altogether 1200-ish lines in the file. I want to make a data frame where each word and their english translation are paired together.

Comment: If the lines are paired,  then repeating  `rbind( t(mydata[1:2,]), t(mydata[2:3,]) `  will do it for you.  Obviously you'd want a loop or `*apply` function over  N/2 row pairs.